# App engine flexible http request still takes user to default service even after defining dispatch.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I am using App Engine Flexible environment and I have multiple services deployed in my App Engine. So I connected multiple sub domains to my app engine. In order to assign one subdomain to each service, I defined `dispatch.yaml` file. Here is how it looks like

```
dispatch:

- url: "wscfg.xxxxxxxxx.com/"
  service: default

- url: "onboarding.xxxxxxxxx.com/"
  service: default

- url: "dtnote.xxxxxxxxx.com/"
  service: default

- url: "careco.xxxxxxxxx.com/"
  service: careco

- url: "userman.xxxxxxxxx.com/"
  service: user-management
```

After deploying it to app engine, it shows services with the custom domains specified in `dispatch.yaml` file. So my dispatch file is working correctly. [image]

The problem is when I am trying to access `https://careco.xxxxxxxxx.com/`, it is taking me to `default` service whereas `https://user-management.xxxxxxxxx.com/` is taking me to `userman` service (which is correct).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `dispatch.yaml` file. It needs to have wildcard at the end. So `dispatch.yaml` should look like

```
dispatch:

- url: "wscfg.xxxxxxxxx.com/*"
  service: default

- url: "onboarding.xxxxxxxxx.com/*"
  service: default

- url: "dtnote.xxxxxxxxx.com/*"
  service: default

- url: "careco.xxxxxxxxx.com/*"
  service: careco

- url: "userman.xxxxxxxxx.com/*"
  service: user-management
```